# Is it possible to solve the Poisson equation with the finite element method?

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to replicate the article:

Numerical Solution of a Two Dimensional Poisson Equation
with Dirichlet Boundary Conditions, doi: 10.11648/j.ajam.20150306.19.

I liked the article very much. Unfortunately, all my attempts to invert the stiffness matrix by a numerical method for solving linear systems seem not to work.

The method, the Gauss-Seidel, which is used doesn't seem to work either. Can you give me some ideas on where the error is?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//compile as  gcc main.cpp -o finite
 
double* new_double(int N)
{
   return (double*)malloc( (size_t)(N*sizeof(double)));
}

int* new_int(int N)
{
   return (int*)malloc( (size_t)(N*sizeof(int)));
}


int **new_matrix_int( long nrh,  long nch)
/* allocate a double matrix with subscript range m[0..nrh][0..nch] */
{
    long i, nrow=nrh+1,ncol=nch+1;
    int **m;

    /* allocate pointers to rows */
    m=(int **) malloc((size_t)((nrow)*sizeof(int*)));
    if (!m) fprintf(stderr,"allocation failure");

    /* allocate rows and set pointers to them */
    m[0]=(int *) malloc((size_t)((nrow*ncol)*sizeof(int)));
    if (!m[0]) fprintf(stderr,"allocation failure");

    for(i=1;i<=nrh;i++) m[i]=m[i-1]+ncol;

    /* return pointer to array of pointers to rows */
    return m;
}


double **new_matrix_double( long nrh,  long nch)
/* allocate a double matrix with subscript range m[0..nrh][0..nch] */
{
    long i, nrow=nrh+1,ncol=nch+1;
    double **m;

    /* allocate pointers to rows */
    m=(double **) malloc((size_t)((nrow)*sizeof(double*)));
    if (!m) fprintf(stderr,"allocation failure");

    /* allocate rows and set pointers to them */
    m[0]=(double *) malloc((size_t)((nrow*ncol)*sizeof(double)));
    if (!m[0]) fprintf(stderr,"allocation failure");

    for(i=1;i<=nrh;i++) m[i]=m[i-1]+ncol;

    /* return pointer to array of pointers to rows */
    return m;
}



struct element 
{

  int Id;   
  int i,  j,  k;
  int ei, ej, ek;
  int si, sj, sk;
  double xV, yV;
} ;

struct node 
{
  int Id;   
  double x, y;
  int mark;
} ;




typedef struct element ELEMENT;
typedef struct node NODE;



ELEMENT* new_element(int N)
{
   return (ELEMENT*)malloc( (size_t)(N*sizeof(ELEMENT)));
}
 
NODE* new_node(int N)
{
   return (NODE*)malloc( (size_t)(N*sizeof(NODE)));
}



int Ne,Nn;

ELEMENT *ele;
NODE *nod;

int **nod_ele;
int *N_nod_len;
double **K;
double *F;
double *FF;




void getK(void)
{

   double ai[3],bi[3],ci[3],Ae;
   double xi,yi;
   double xj,yj;
   double xk,yk;

   int ni,nj,nk;
   double fac_1=0.0;
   double temp;

   double KK[3][3];


   fprintf(stderr,"Here Ok\n");


   for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   
      KK[k][i]=0.0;
     
   }}


   for (int J=0;J<Ne;J++){
      
      xi= nod[ ele[J].i ].x ;
      yi= nod[ ele[J].i ].y ;

      xj= nod[ ele[J].j ].x ;
      yj= nod[ ele[J].j ].y ;

      xk= nod[ ele[J].k ].x ;
      yk= nod[ ele[J].k ].y ;


      ai[0]= xj*yk-xk*yj;
      bi[0]= yj-yk;
      ci[0]= xk-xj;


      Ae=0.5*(  (xj*yk-xk*yj) - xi* (yk-yj) + yi*(xk-xj) ) ;


      xi= nod[ ele[J].j ].x ;
      yi= nod[ ele[J].j ].y ;

      xj= nod[ ele[J].k ].x ;
      yj= nod[ ele[J].k ].y ;

      xk= nod[ ele[J].i ].x ;
      yk= nod[ ele[J].i ].y ;


      ai[1]= xj*yk-xk*yj;
      bi[1]= yj-yk;
      ci[1]= xk-xj;


      xi= nod[ ele[J].k ].x ;
      yi= nod[ ele[J].k ].y ;

      xj= nod[ ele[J].i ].x ;
      yj= nod[ ele[J].i ].y ;

      xk= nod[ ele[J].j ].x ;
      yk= nod[ ele[J].j ].y ;


      ai[2]= xj*yk-xk*yj;
      bi[2]= yj-yk;
      ci[2]= xk-xj;


      ni=ele[J].i;
      nj=ele[J].j;
      nk=ele[J].k;

 
 
      KK[0][0]=( bi[0] * bi[0] + ci[0] * ci[0] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);
      KK[0][1]=( bi[0] * bi[1] + ci[0] * ci[1] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);
      KK[0][2]=( bi[0] * bi[2] + ci[0] * ci[2] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);

      KK[1][0]=( bi[1] * bi[0] + ci[1] * ci[0] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);
      KK[1][1]=( bi[1] * bi[1] + ci[1] * ci[1] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);
      KK[1][2]=( bi[1] * bi[2] + ci[1] * ci[2] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);

      KK[2][0]=( bi[2] * bi[0] + ci[2] * ci[0] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);
      KK[2][1]=( bi[2] * bi[1] + ci[2] * ci[1] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);
      KK[2][2]=( bi[2] * bi[2] + ci[2] * ci[2] )*1.0/(4.0*Ae);



      K[ni][ni]  = K[ni][ni]  + KK[0][0];
      K[ni][nj]  = K[ni][nj]  + KK[0][1];
      K[ni][nk]  = K[ni][nk]  + KK[0][2];


      K[nj][ni]  = K[nj][ni]  + KK[1][0];
      K[nj][nj]  = K[nj][nj]  + KK[1][1];
      K[nj][nk]  = K[nj][nk]  + KK[1][2];

      K[nk][ni]  = K[nk][ni]  + KK[2][0];
      K[nk][nj]  = K[nk][nj]  + KK[2][1];
      K[nk][nk]  = K[nk][nk]  + KK[2][2];

   }

}






// local assembly of the load vector


void getF(void)
{

   double ai[3],bi[3],ci[3],Ae;
   double xi,yi;
   double xj,yj;
   double xk,yk;
   double xc,yc;
   double xd,yd;


   for (int J=0;J<Ne;J++){

      xi= nod[ ele[J].i ].x ;
      yi= nod[ ele[J].i ].y ;

      xj= nod[ ele[J].j ].x ;
      yj= nod[ ele[J].j ].y ;

      xk= nod[ ele[J].k ].x ;
      yk= nod[ ele[J].k ].y ;


      Ae=0.5*(  (xj*yk-xk*yj) - xi* (yk-yj) + yi*(xk-xj) ) ;


      FF[ele[J].i]= FF[ele[J].i]+ Ae/12.0*(2*F[ele[J].i] +   F[ele[J].j]+  F[ele[J].k]) ;
      FF[ele[J].j]= FF[ele[J].j]+ Ae/12.0*(  F[ele[J].i] + 2*F[ele[J].j]+  F[ele[J].k]) ;
      FF[ele[J].k]= FF[ele[J].k]+ Ae/12.0*(  F[ele[J].i] +   F[ele[J].j]+2*F[ele[J].k]) ;

   }

// the load vector as in your article
      FF[1]=0.0104;
      FF[2]=0.0417;
      FF[3]=0.0208;
      FF[4]=0.0417;
      FF[5]=0.0104;
      FF[6]=0.0417;
      FF[7]=0.0417;
      FF[8]=0.0833;
      FF[9]=0.0417;
      FF[10]=0.0417;
      FF[11]=0.0208;
      FF[12]=0.0833;
      FF[13]=0.0417;
      FF[14]=0.0833;
      FF[15]=0.0208;
      FF[16]=0.0417;
      FF[17]=0.0417;
      FF[18]=0.0833;
      FF[19]=0.0417;
      FF[20]=0.0417;
      FF[21]=0.0104;
      FF[22]=0.0417;
      FF[23]=0.0208;
      FF[24]=0.0417;
      FF[25]=0.0104;


}




//for solving the linear system

#define TINY 1.0e-20;

void ludcmp(double **a, int n, int *indx, double *d)
{
    int i,imax,j,k;
    double big,dum,sum,temp;
    double *vv;

    vv=new_double(n+1);
    *d=1.0;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        big=0.0;
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
            if ((temp=fabs(a[i][j])) > big) big=temp;
        if (big == 0.0) fprintf(stderr,"Singular matrix in routine ludcmp");
        vv[i]=1.0/big;
    }
    for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {
        for (i=1;i<j;i++) {
            sum=a[i][j];
            for (k=1;k<i;k++) sum -= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
            a[i][j]=sum;
        }
        big=0.0;
        for (i=j;i<=n;i++) {
            sum=a[i][j];
            for (k=1;k<j;k++)
                sum -= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
            a[i][j]=sum;
            if ( (dum=vv[i]*fabs(sum)) >= big) {
                big=dum;
                imax=i;
            }
        }
        if (j != imax) {
            for (k=1;k<=n;k++) {
                dum=a[imax][k];
                a[imax][k]=a[j][k];
                a[j][k]=dum;
            }
            *d = -(*d);
            vv[imax]=vv[j];
        }
        indx[j]=imax;
        if (a[j][j] == 0.0) a[j][j]=TINY;
        if (j != n) {
            dum=1.0/(a[j][j]);
            for (i=j+1;i<=n;i++) a[i][j] *= dum;
        }
    }
    free(vv);
}
#undef TINY



void lubksb(double **a, int n, int *indx, double b[])
{
    int i,ii=0,ip,j;
    double sum;

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        ip=indx[i];
        sum=b[ip];
        b[ip]=b[i];
        if (ii)
            for (j=ii;j<=i-1;j++) sum -= a[i][j]*b[j];
        else if (sum) ii=i;
        b[i]=sum;
    }
    for (i=n;i>=1;i--) {
        sum=b[i];
        for (j=i+1;j<=n;j++) sum -= a[i][j]*b[j];
        b[i]=sum/a[i][i];
    }
}


double * F_gaus_seidel(double *x)
{
     double *y;
     y=new_double(Nn+1);
     for(int k=1;k<=Nn;k++){
        y[k]=0.0;
        for(int j=1;j<=Nn;j++){

         if(k!=j) 
         y[k] = y[k] - K[k][j]*x[j];

        }
         y[k]= y[k]+ FF[k] ;
     }
     return y;
}

//the main code



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   int dum,cont;
   FILE *fd;


   double d;
   int n,*indx;

   //opening the elements file

   fd=fopen("example.e","r");
   fscanf(fd,"%d\n",&Ne);

   fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",Ne); 
   
   ele=new_element(Ne);

   fprintf(stderr,"elements\n");

   for(int  k=0;k<Ne;k++)
   {
      fscanf(fd,"%d %d %d %d \n",
      &ele[k].Id,&ele[k].i,&ele[k].j,&ele[k].k);

   }
   fclose(fd);

   //opening the nodes file   

   fd=fopen("example.n","r");
   fscanf(fd,"%d\n",&Nn);
   fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",Nn); 

   nod=new_node(Nn+1);


   fprintf(stderr,"nodes\n");
   for(int  k=1;k<=Nn;k++)
   {
      dum=fscanf(fd     ,"%d %lf %lf %d\n", &nod[k].Id,&nod[k].x ,&nod[k].y,&nod[k].mark ) ;
      fprintf(stderr,"%d %lf %lf %d\n", nod[k].Id,nod[k].x ,nod[k].y,nod[k].mark ) ;
   }   

   fclose(fd);



   K=new_matrix_double(Nn+1,Nn+1);
   F=new_double(Nn+1);
   FF=new_double(Nn+1);


   
   for(int k=1;k<=Nn;k++){
      FF[k]=0;
      F[k]=-1.0; 
   }


   for(int k=1;k<=Nn;k++){
   for(int i=1;i<=Nn;i++){
   
      K[k][i]=0.0;
     
   }}
  
   getK();   //calculates the stiffness  Matrix


   fprintf(stderr,"stiffness  Matrix\n");
   for(int k=1;k<=Nn;k++){  
      for(int i=1;i<=Nn;i++){
         fprintf(stderr,"K(%d,%d)=%f;\n",k,i,K[k][i] );;
      }
   }

   getF();       //calculates the load vector

   fprintf(stderr,"load vector\n");
   for(int i=1;i<=Nn;i++)
      fprintf(stderr,"FF(%d)=%e;\n",i,FF[i]);        



   double *diagonal;
   double *X;

   diagonal=new_double(Nn+1);
   X=new_double(Nn+1);

   for(int k=1;k<=Nn;k++)
      diagonal[k]=K[k][k];
   


   //solution by the Gauss Seidel method
   
   for(int i=1;i<=Nn;i++) X[i]=0.0;


   fprintf(stderr,"Gauss Seidel Iteration \n");
   fprintf(stderr,"iteration  7     8     9    12    \n");
   for(int k_it=1;k_it<=15;k_it++){

      X=F_gaus_seidel(X);
      for(int i=1;i<=Nn;i++) X[i]=1.0/diagonal[i]*X[i];

      fprintf(stderr,"%d %f %f %f %f\n",k_it,X[7],X[8],X[9],X[12]);
   }
    
    //solves the linear system K x= FF using LU descomposition method
   indx=new_int(Nn+1);
   n=Nn;

   ludcmp(K,n,indx,&d); 
   lubksb(K,n,indx,FF);

 
   fprintf(stderr,"Solution by the LU descomposition method\n");
   for(int i=1;i<=Nn;i++)
    fprintf(stderr,"X[%d]: %f\n",i,FF[i]);

   fprintf(stderr,"Neither the iterative nor the exact method seem to solve the system\n");

   

}
```

the files needed are example.e

```
32
   0    1    2    6  
   1    2    7    6  
   2    2    3    8  
   3    2    8    7  
   4    3    4    8  
   5    4    9    8  
   6    4    5    10 
   7    4    10    9 
   8    6    7    12 
   9    6    12   11 
   10   7    8    12 
   11   8    13   12 
   12   8    9    14 
   13   8    14    13
   14   9    10    14
   15   10   15    14
   16   11    12    16
   17   12    17    16
   18   12    13    18
   19   12    18    17
   20   13    14    18
   21   14    19    18
   22   14    15    20
   23   14    20    19
   24   16    17    22
   25   16    22    21
   26   17    18    22
   27   22    18    23
   28   18    19    24
   29   18    24    23
   30   19    20    24
   31   20    25    24
```

and example.n

```
25
1   0.000000 0.000000 1
2   0.250000 0.000000 1
3   0.500000 0.000000 1
4   0.750000 0.000000 1
5   1.000000 0.000000 1
6   0.000000 0.250000 1
7   0.250000 0.250000 1
8   0.500000 0.250000 1
9   0.750000 0.250000 1
10  1.000000 0.250000 1
11  0.000000 0.500000 1
12  0.250000 0.500000 1
13  0.500000 0.500000 1
14  0.750000 0.500000 1
15  1.000000 0.500000 1
16  0.000000 0.750000 1
17  0.250000 0.750000 1
18  0.500000 0.750000 1
19  0.750000 0.750000 1
20  1.000000 0.750000 1
21  0.000000 1.000000 1
22  0.250000 1.000000 1
23  0.500000 1.000000 1
24  0.750000 1.000000 1
25  1.000000 1.000000 1
```

Comment: The effort to _"Can you give me some ideas on where the error is?"_ is a pretty broad request.   Has it not been possible for you to run in debug mode, and use break points to walk through the code while comparing intermediate results, with a list of expectations.  If so, where are the concentrations of errors that you have seen?  if not, then try it to see what you can find and post them as part of your post to give potential help some inkling of where to look.

Comment: maybe you'll find someone willing to pour thru all this code, but don't hold your breath. Can you narrow down the problem at all? Use a smaller data set and find where things deviate stepping thru with a debugger? Any indication where the problem starts? You're much more likely to get help providing a [mre] instead of a full code dump.

Comment: Thanks Guys. My belief is that the finite element method has a serious drawback. The linear systems it produce are not very well behaved. The program runs without any problem. It is not a computational problem but I believe it is a theoretical limitation. This is the simplest problem I found on internet. There  are very well written books and articles but I wanted  a simple example. I run the method with very simple meshes and the same problem. So I needed a little feedback if someone has been able to solve a Poisson problem with the finite element.